# Need to create an Objective-C method in Xcode and invoke it from JavaScript Cordova App

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have created a `Cordova` App and created `iOS` platform. I have a requirement to create an `Objective-C` method in `Xcode` and invoke it from `JavaScript/HTML` page.

The code in AppDelegate.h is

```
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate : CDVAppDelegate {}

@end
```

The code in AppDelegate.m is

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

Any step-by-step tutorial or example?

Comment: What is an "xcode function"?

Comment: Objective C function? I am new to xocde/objective C. Need is a call from javascript and print NSLOG(@"Successfully a obj c method called from a javascript function");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cordova, a native function that can be called from JavaScript is made using a plugin. Take a look at the [Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/) to create your own plugin or search for [already existing plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) that implement the functionality that you need.

---

This sample is extracted from the [iOS Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html):

**1. Declare javascript function**

```
window.echo = function(str, callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);
};
```

**2. Implement platform specific code:**

```
/********* Echo.h Cordova Plugin Header *******/

#import 

@interface Echo : CDVPlugin

- (void)echo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end

/********* Echo.m Cordova Plugin Implementation *******/

#import "Echo.h"
#import 

@implementation Echo

- (void)echo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if (echo != nil && [echo length] > 0) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:echo];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

**3. Create plugin config file:**

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="Echo">
            <param name="ios-package" value="Echo" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

**4. Call this function from Javascript:**

```
window.echo("echome", function(echoValue) {
    alert(echoValue == "echome"); // should alert true.
});
```